# How to Terminate Processes if Disconnect from Docker Container

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running that is shared by some people who are not too experienced with using command line tools. A user "logs in" by `docker exec -it container_name bash`.

If one starts up a process like `python` but then gets disconnected from the network, the `python` process is not terminated and continues to use resources. I know that people familiar with command line tools can find this `python` process by `ps aux` or similar, but in the interest of the people I help I was wondering if there is a way to *automatically* terminate processes of a user if they `exit` or lose connection from the container?

Comment: Remember that anyone who can run `docker` commands can pretty easily root the entire system; I'd avoid encouraging people to `docker exec` if you don't trust them with root access on the host.  In general I'd suggest reserving `docker exec` for debugging the main process in a container.